# How to pass parameter after baseurl in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Base URL: http://localhost/f1/

and I am passing parameter in URL like:
    http://localhost/f1/user1

and I am trying to print

```
function index(){
    echo $this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

I want to print `User1` in the controller. How to achieve this?

Comment: Now, What is the issue?

Comment: 404 not found showing.

Comment: Have you set your `base_url`?

Comment: yes above I have mentioned. http://localhost/f1/

Comment: Try to get `User1` as a function parameter function index($url1){ echo $url1;}

Comment: No base url is localhost/f1/ and I am passing immediate after this user1 parameter. means Irrespective it's index method.
I know it is getting error because of default method i.e index().

Comment: yes using _remap($url1) tried but I want to pass in url @DanishAli

Comment: I want to replace default index method to parameter IN url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config your rout and add this:

```
$route['Controller_Name/(:any)'] = 'Controller_Name/index/$1';
```

Here you go with your controller

```
class Controller_Name extends CI_Controller {
  function index($prm){
    echo $prm;
  }
}
```

Have fun.... 
you can have how many uri you want....

Answer (score 0):

Read here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html -> `Passing URI Segments to your methods`

```
/products/shoes/sandals/123

<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

        public function shoes($sandals, $id)
        {
                echo $sandals;
                echo $id;
        }
}
```

Comment: if there will be index method then?

Comment: it will be like `example.com/index.php/home/index/param1`

Answer (score 0):

After `base_url` segemnts/parameter can get like this

Make sure `base_url` and URL helper is set in the `application/config/config.php` and `application/config/autoload.php` file respectively

Suppose, calling a function with a **anchor tag**

```
<a href="<?= base_url('HomeController/index/'.$url1)?> ">Index</a>
```

In the above line, `HomeController` is controller name, `index` in the function name and `$url1` is the parameter

```
class HomeController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($url1){
         echo $url1;
    }
}
```

Also, `$this->uri->segment()` can be used.

Comment: Yes correct. it will work if I pass parameter from controller but If I want to pass from URL then?

Comment: Login is same for URL also.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your question is that you want a remap without using your method and pass the parameter directly after your controller?

You can user `_remap` and check if it matched a method process it normally or pass it to your default method directly and now you won't need to use `index` in your url as you intended.

```
public function _remap($method)
{
        if ($method === 'some_method_in_your_controller')
        {
                $this->$method();
        }
        else
        {
                $this->index($method);
        }
}
```

Now lets say your url is like this `http://localhost/controller/parameter` then if this parameter matches a method it will call that method if not it will pass it as a parameter to you `index`.

Comment: @Rishi is this what you want!

Answer (score 0):

define your controller in config/routes.php.it will call your index function by default.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controllername';
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether you loaded the url helper. Only then it will work as expected. Either auto-load it or call it in the controller.