# How to get data from a JavaScript to controller and store it in the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to get the location from this JavaScript to the controller and store it in the database:

```js
var currPosition;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  updatePosition(position);
  setInterval(function() {
    var lat = currPosition.coords.latitude;
    var lng = currPosition.coords.longitude;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myURL/location.php",
      data: 'x=' + lat + '&y=' + lng,
      cache: false
    });
  }, 1000);
}, errorCallback);

var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  updatePosition(position);
});

function updatePosition(position) {
  currPosition = position;
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  var msg = "Can't get your location. Error = ";
  if (error.code == 1)
    msg += "PERMISSION_DENIED";
  else if (error.code == 2)
    msg += "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE";
  else if (error.code == 3)
    msg += "TIMEOUT";
  msg += ", msg = " + error.message;
  alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: You are getting any error? Whats your question?

Comment: iam new to codeigniter framework please can you tell me how to post those watch-position coordinates from java script to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send post with `.ajax()`:

```
// ....
let formData = new FormData();
const lat = currPosition.coords.latitude;
const lng = currPosition.coords.longitude;
formData.append("x", lat);
formData.append("y", y lng;
$.ajax({
    url: "myURL/location.php", // update this with you url
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        const response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
//....
```

To receive post data in [codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) :

```
$x = $this->input->post('x');
$y = $this->input->post('y');
```

Comment: i still get null values " INSERT INTO location (x, y) VALUES (NULL, NULL)" 
Uncaught ReferenceError: base_url is not defined

Comment: @KishanChandra may be you not declare class extend `CI_Controller`.. See this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944667/how-to-pass-parameter-after-baseurl-in-codeigniter

Comment: hi, thanks i managed to solve it just by adding    <script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';</script>

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change `uri` parameter to codeginter route that you have

```
setInterval(function(){
    ....
    url:  "change this to codeigniter route url", 
    ....
}, 1000);
```

then in the controller you just need to save those parameter,

```
class X extends CI_Controller{

    function update_position(){
        $x = $this->input->post('x');
        $y = $this->input->post('y');

        // then save it using model or query.
        $this->model_name->insert([...])
    }
}
```

Comment: i still get null values   " INSERT INTO `location` (`x`, `y`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: base_url is not defined